# Two array of object merge in another array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
arr1 = [{name : xyz}, {age: 26}, {sex : m}] 

arr2 = [{place: somwhere}, {std: 6}]
```

result should be

```
  arr3 =[
         {name : xyz, place: somwhere, std: 6}, 
         {age: 26 , place: null , std: null}, 
         {sex : m, place: null , std: null}
        ]
```

Comment: How come some have `place: somwhere` and others `place: null`? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You only have two data types there strings and number, you can't merge undefined data types of objects.

```
var arr1 = [{ name: "xyz" }, { age: 26 }, { sex: "m" }]

var arr2 = [{ place: "somwhere" }, { std: 6 }]

var arr3 = [];

arr3.push(arr1, arr2)

console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, return a new Array object:

```
Object.assign({}, arr1, arr2,arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two arrays like this:

```
const res = [...arr1, ...arr2]
```

but that will give you an array like this as result

```
[ {name: "xyz"}, {age: 26}, {sex: "m"}, {place: "somwhere"}, {std: 6} ]
```

Which is not what you want.

You could also merge one of the items from the first array with the second, like this

```
const res2 = arr1.map( (key, index) => [arr1[index], ...arr2])

console.log(res2)
```

But that will give you a result like this:

```
[ 
  [ {name: "xyz"}, {place: "somwhere"}, {std: 6}],
  [ {age: 26}, {place: "somwhere"}, {std: 6}],
  [ {sex: "m"}, {place: "somwhere"}, {std: 6}]
]
```

Which is also not exactly what you wanted.

If you want to achieve exactly the result you want to, I guess you would have to have some sort of logic between the the two arrays, for instance having the values you want merged in different indexes of the second array:

```
const arr1 = [{name : 'xyz'}, {age: 26}, {sex : 'm'}]

const arr2 = [ [{place: 'somwhere'}, {std: 6}], [{place: null}, {std: null}], [{place:null}, {std: null}]]

const res = arr1.map( (key, index) => [arr1[index], ...arr2[index]])

console.debug('res:',res)
```

This gives you the exact result you want, but has a different setup. If you say more about the logic behind, there might be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will put the logic in java, convert it to javascript

```
 Object[] arr1= {"benz",26,'m'};

 Object[] arr2= {"somewhere",6};

Object[][] arr3= new Object[arr1.length][arr1.length];

for(int r=0;r<arr3.length;r++)
{
    for(int c=0;c<1;c++)
    {
        if(r!=0)
            System.out.println("name : "+arr1[r]+", place : "+null+", std : "+null);
        else
            System.out.println("name : "+arr1[r]+", place : "+arr2[c]+", std : "+arr2[c+1]);

    }
}
```

}